# Vuetify Slider is Preventing Form Submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms, vuetify.js

For some reason when I add a slider to my Vuetify form, pressing enter while in the text input no longer submits the form. When I remove the slider, the form submits when I type in the text input and press enter. When I add it back, pressing enter in the text input does nothing. Why is that?

```html
<template>
<v-form
  v-model="valid"
  lazy-validation
  v-on:submit.prevent="search"
>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <v-text-field
          outlined
          v-model="searchString"
          class="pa-5"
          label="Search for submissions, attachments, samples etc."
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <v-slider
          label="Max results"
          class="pa-5"
          v-model="limit"
          max="500"
          min="10"
          step="10"
          ticks="always"
          thumb-label="always"
        ></v-slider>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-row>
      <v-col class="text-right">
        <v-btn class="mr-4" color="success" @click="search"
          >Search</v-btn
        >
        <v-btn @click="clear">Clear</v-btn>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</v-form>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      limit: 100,
      searchResults: null,
      searchString: "",
      valid: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    search() {
       alert('searching!');
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML forms only submit on enter if there is a single input in them. If you have more than one input you also need a submit button for this to happen. You can add `type="submit"` to the v-btn to turn it into a submit button.

Comment: Jesus you're kidding me. I have been web developing for 13+ years ‍♂️. Worked like a charm